# Why does the TypeScript HttpClient try to parse a plain text string as JSON?

Tags: angular, typescript, http-post

I'm using the following method to send out a POST request in Angular TypeScript. The request takes a string as a parameter and returns a string as well.

```
sendPostRequest(postData: string): Observable<string> {

  let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  header = header.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  return this.http.post<string>("http://myurl.com", "data=" + postData, {headers: header});
}
```

I trigger the request and process the response with the following method:

```
this.sendPostRequest("myData").subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response);
});
```

In the browser console, I get a `HTTPErrorResponse`, with the error reading: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`.

The thing ist, the string which it tries to parse is the *response*. Checking the network tab as well as sending the request through Postman shows that the server handles the request without a problem. Expanding the `http.post()` call with `.pipe(response => { response.subscribe(data => console.log(data)); return response; });` triggers a second `HTTPErrorMessage`. Removing `data => console.log(data));` from that line also removes the second error response.

So what I'm getting from this, is that there is no problem with the request itself, but the `HttpClient` then tries to parse it for some reason, and instead of a normal error it triggers a `HTTPErrorMessage`, even though the error happens in the client.

So that leaves me with the question: **What am I doing wrong?** I've always used Observables this way and searching on this site only yields questions from people not subscribing to their Observables.

To be clear: There is no JSON supposed to be used anywhere in this exchange. But for some reason the client tries to parse the response anyway.

Comment: Second argument of post should be an object, not a string. E.g. `{ data: postData }`.

Comment: @GunnarB. That's only when you want to send JSON, right? But the server doesn't expect JSON. Again, the request gets processed without a problem. It is the _response_ that triggers the JSON exception. There is no JSON supposed to be used anywhere in this exchange. But for some reason the client tries to use it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, my colleague's Google got the right answer. Apparently, the there are typed and non-typed versions of the `http.post()` method. And the typed one always tries to return JSON. So the solution is to remove the type and then add an optional parameter which specifies the response type.

```
sendPostRequest(postData: string): Observable<string> {

  let header: HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
  header = header.set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  return this.http.post("http://myurl.com", "data=" + postData, {headers: header, responseType: "text"});
}
```